# Is it necessary to create couple program OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning OpenGL and want to create simple program. I want to render different meshes with different shaders. Should I recreate program or I must reuse created program? (program - shader program, created by calling glCreateProgram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to re-use the linked program(s), it's just usually *much* faster than re-compiling/linking them each frame/drawcall.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You mean I should create for all my meshes programs?

Comment: @Airat: No, just that you shouldn't recompile/relink the shaders each frame/drawcall.  The optimal/reasonable number of shaders is going to be very program-specific.  Some can get by with a single shader, others have dozens.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you.